# Spring Based JMS Consumer's not starting after DB fail over

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms, oracle-aq

I'm writing Spring based JMS Consumers for my application, everything working fine in sunny days, But in case of DB machine restart its stoped working and not getting connection with DB, while other DB components getting proper DB connection. One more thing if I am restarting only orcl service of oracle consumer working fine but If i restarted whole machine they are not working.

Comment: Are the consumers actively requesting a new connection? If yes, whats the exception that occurs there?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker if DB machine is down consumers are doing nothing even they are not throwing exception and not printing any log.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about your consumer? Are you using a message listener container or are you creating a `MessageConsumer` yourself? (either directly or through `JmsTemplate`)

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll I'm using AdtMessageListenerContainer of spring-data which extends DefaultMessageListnerContainer through JMSTemplete.

Comment: You haven't provided any configuration or source code. For example, I'm interested if you're getting the JMS related resources through JNDI? Also, relevant configuration of the listener container, pooling connection factory, queues/topics might be important.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` is fully self-recovering in case of the broker being temporarily unavailable, means it will automatically reconnect according to the `recoveryInterval` value.

can you see the following or similar exception in you application logs:

```
ERROR DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed - trying to recover
```

if so, then check you connection factory configuration and try by NOT using connection factory which does the connection caching itself. i.e. `SingleConnectionFactory` or `CachingConnectionFactory`.

Comment: thanks @Ahsan fro reply but in my case there are no more consumer logs after DB failure and in thread dump its showing only in receive message.

Comment: And yes I am using connection pooling with OracleDataSource, and every thing working fine with legecy JMS code without spring.

Comment: seems to be the connection caching issue... try by using a non-caching connection factory as stated above.

Comment: I'm using OracleAQ for JMS.

Comment: when I am using CachingConnectionFactory as suggest by yuou is giving me exception : 'java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11 cannot be cast to oracle.jms.AQjmsSession'  while SingleConnectionFactory working fine but this class dont have power to reset connections after failover.

Comment: actually i suggested NOT to use such connection factory which do connection caching... SingleConnectionFactory also does caching internally.

Comment: ok First I was not using such classes but now with SingleConnectionFactory working perfect as i wanted.